# Why does RegOpenCurrentUser have a samDesired parameter?

Tags: windows, registry

I'm having a difficult time figuring out why RegOpenCurrentUser has a samDesired parameter at all.  Surely it's always going to be KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS or even 0?

A subsequent call to RegOpenKeyEx is required to do anything meaningful in the impesronated user's registry profile. Wouldn't you pass the specific samDesired value to that call?   Are there any access requirements for the first parameter (hKey) to RegOpenKeyEx?

RegOpenCurrentUser returns a handle to the root of a registry hive. I can't think of any scenario other than installing Windows or creating a brand new user profile where anything is done at a hive root.   And if you're running a program as another user, presumably all of that is already done.

RegOpenCurrentUser: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
RegOpenKeyEx: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: KEY_READ is a convenience value that combines several flags.  You'd certainly also consider KEY_WRITE.

Comment: I edited the OP out from under @Hans Passant's comment.   The point is that right at the base of the hive you dont do anything but go to the other subkeys.